# Is there anyway in matplotlib to clip scattergraph plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I've made the following scatterplot.  I have an outlier on the positive side of the graph and also the negative end of the graph.

[image: Scatterplot]

I think normally if I were plotting this using `matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot` I could use `clip_on`

But since this was graphed using `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter` there is no clipping parameter.  Do I basically have to adjust the data somehow?  Or is there a matplotlib way of doing this?

Comment: you could just set the x axis limits manually with `plt.xlim()`?

Comment: If the x and y are numpy arrays, clipping can be achieved via numpy's masking:  `plt.scatter(x[(x > xmin) & (x < xmax)], y[(x > xmin) & (x < xmax)], ...)`

Comment: thanks @cripcate!  I was making it harder than it was.